# How does one explain the curve between the distance and output of the secondary coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm working on a lab, and I thought that the power in the secondary coil of a transformer should change with distance according to the inverse cube law because of the flux density changing according to that , and the power being proportional to that (Cardona et al., 2020). But my measurements show a 0.9998 correlation with an exponential curve. How could you possibly explain this? Naturally, input power into the primary coil was kept constant.
[image]

Comment: (a) The inverse cube law for the flux density produced by a coil applies only at much greater distances from the coil than the coil's dimensions. (b) I wonder how you measured the secondary power. Did you connect a resistor across the coil? (c) I'd expect the power to be proportional to the *square* of the peak flux density.

Comment: "With four parameters I can fit an elephant.  With five I can make him wiggle his trunk." — John von Neumann